# AWS create user only with S3 permissions

Tags: amazon-s3

I know how to create a user through AWS Console en IAM, but I wonder where or how should I set the permissions to that user in order that he only could:

- upload/delete files to a specific folder in a specific S3 bucket

I have this bucket:

[image]

So I wonder if I have to set up the permissions in that interface, or directly in the user in IAM service

I'm creating a Group there with this policy:

[image]

but for "Write" and "Read" there are a lot of policies, which ones do I need only for write/read files in a specific bucket?

Edit: Currently I have this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::static.XXXXXX.com/images/carousel/*",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I wonder if that is enough to:

- log in AWS Console
- go to S3 buckets and delete/read objects in the folder of the bucket that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a role to that user that gets a custom policy ([Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_managed-policies.html)).

There you can choose the service, the actions which you want to allow and also the resource which are whitelisted.

Comment: Something like this? https://i.imgur.com/vh12vP5.png  I'm not sure if it is enough with those 2 permissions

Comment: So depends on your use-case. If you know how the file you want to delete is called you just need DeleteObject and PutObject for upload. If you want to for example choose the file that you want to delete, then you need the ListBucket policy as well.

Comment: I see, I can't find that policy on the list

Comment: It's actually ListBucket, was a mistake on my side.

Comment: ah, it's already set it :D I will edit my question with the JSON of the policy

Comment: In addition, you don't need to use groups if you just want to set if for one user. You can create a role, to which you attach your custom policy. You then assign the role to your user. Of course you can use groups as well, depends on your use-case.

Comment: If I was able to help you, accepting the answer would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks mate. I need a group becase more than 1 user will do this actions (maybe), thanks again.

Comment: Now I need to `This policy defines some actions, resources, or conditions that do not provide permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition.` I have to give more permissions, I think I will stop writing comments, I must continue alone, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a resource based policy that is attached with S3 or an identity based policy attached to an IAM User, Group or Role.

[Identity-based policies and resource-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html)

You can attach below identity policy to the user to upload/delete files to a specific folder in a specific S3 bucket.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::SAMPLE-BUCKET-NAME/foldername"
    }
]
```

}

For more details, refer [Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)